# Return from parent function in PHP extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I want to write a PHP extension that provides the following functionality (simplified example):

```
function myFunc($a, $b) {
    maybe_early_exit();
    return $a + b;
}
```

Where based on some logic in the extension, `maybe_early_exit` *might* cause the parent function to return early with a specific return value. Essentially my extension needs to sometimes pop from the function stack and set the previous function call's return value at the call site.

Is this possible in a PHP extension? No answer is too hacky to accept ;)

Comment: So, sometimes you need to return `maybe_early_exit`'s return value, and other times you want to return `$a + $b`? Why on earth would you need to do that?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, and it seems like a very strange requirement. How do you know that it's just the parent function you need to return from, maybe it should actually be the grandparent or higher?

Comment: This is probably a use for throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm intentionally not going into "why on earth" I want to do this, because I'm interested in whether it can be done, not being lectured on whether I should or how weird it is.